# Query by non-ascii characters

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Python, on Google App Engine platform.
Let's say I have in my Data Store the following code :

```
class names(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

and there are names like :

```
name1 = Beyoncé
name2 = El Súper Clásico
```

with non-ascii charachters.

When I make a query like :

```
q_1 = names.all().filter('name =', name1)
```

It doesn't work, the comparison is wrong.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?
I tried encoding the "name" to UTF-8, but it didn't work also.

Comment: how were the names (not the best name btw) objects introduced to the database? did you supply them via POST form? If so, it is possible that you did not unquote them. For example, if you send Beyoncé via POST it becomes "Beyonc%C3%A9", you need to use urllib2.unquote() on it before saving it to the database.

Comment: I use unqoute before saving it to DB, and it still ain't working

Comment: I store it with the constructor : names(name=urllib.unquote(setext)), is there any doffernce between urllib2 to urllib ?

Comment: no, there is no difference. well, just print the two values, the one in the database and the one you are matching against, then you will see how they differ.

Comment: It didn't help, they seem to be equal but they are not...

Comment: Ok, i'm not familiar with google app engine per say, but how are you checking for the values? They should be both Beyonc\xc3\xa9

Comment: how can I convert the name I have now to this ?

Comment: You shouldn't turn them into anything, this is just how non-ascii characters are represented in unicode.

import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename="/tmp/myapp.log",
    filemode="w",
)


add logging, the filename should be a path where you can write, the example is for linux, not sure if you are running it. now use the logging.debug(var) on first the variable you are matching against and the one you get from the db. and run the code. post the results here from the log file.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problems with exact matches when correctly decoding input strings (that you get from web request parameters) and correctly encoding output strings (that you save in GAE data storage) in Unicode.

I've tried this snippet in the GAE SDK Interactive Console and it works:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class names(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

some_name = 'Beyonc\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
    # same as: some_name = u'Beyoncé'
    # same as: some_name = u'Beyonc\u00e9'

n = names(name=some_name)
n.put()

q = names.all().filter('name =', some_name)
print q.get().name.encode('utf-8')
    # prints Beyoncé
```

You should debug what is the raw value of the strings you are comparing, i.e., the string saved in the storage and the string passed to the query.

I recommend reading this [article about Unicode by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) if you're not familiar with handling Unicode strings.

In addition to this, if you're running search queries that should match Unicode characters like `u'é'` when input is `'e'`, consider comparing normalized strings:

```
some_name = u'El S\u00faper Cl\u00e1sico' # El Súper Clásico
normalized_name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', some_name).encode('ascii', 'ignore') # El Super Clasico
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still having a problem, when I tried the text you entered here : some_name = 'Beyonc\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8'), and made the query and succeeded, but the raw data I get is not in this ('Beyonc\xc3\xa9') format. it is like this : beyonc%c3%a9

Comment: Then you're missing the part of decoding characters escaped for an URL, e.g.: `from urllib import unquote; some_name =  unquote('beyonc%c3%a9').decode('utf-8')` Hope it helps!